# How to get Enum display name attribute by FieldInfo

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

Currently I'm working on an interesting structure of hardcoded data. Plese don't answer like create a table for this. For sure then I would give it to myself, but my curiosity is too big :).

**This is main enum** with which I'm creating dropdown

```
public enum ImportParamTypeEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "none")]
    None = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Produkty")]
    Product = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Test")]
    Test = 2,
}
```

**Enums below are system params** for above choise. For example if I selected `ImportParamTypeEnum.Product` in `dropdown` then I on the view shows up `MappingColums.Product` system params

```
public class MappingColums
{
    public enum Product
    {
        [Display(Name = "pc")]
        Token = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Nazwa")]
        Name = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Cena")]
        Price = 3,
        [Display(Name = "Ilość")]
        Quantity = 4,
        [Display(Name = "Opis")]
        Description = 5,
    }

    public enum Test
    {
        [Display(Name = "tc")]
        TokenTest = 0,
        [Display(Name = "NazwaTest")]
        NameTest = 1,
        [Display(Name = "CenaTest")]
        PriceTest = 3,
        [Display(Name = "IlośćTest")]
        QuantityTest = 4,
        [Display(Name = "OpisTest")]
        DescriptionTest = 5,
    }
}
```

The code below is a piece of code that creating `ViewModel` (I cut some stuff for simplicity):

```
foreach (var e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ImportParamTypeEnum)))
{
    Type[] mappingColumnsTypes = typeof(MappingColums).GetNestedTypes();
    Type type = mappingColumnsTypes.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Name == e.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
    FieldInfo[] fields = AssemblyHelper.GetFields(type);

    foreach (var f in fields)
    {
        string i = f.GetValue(null).ToString();  
    }
}
```

**AssemblyHelper**

```
public static FieldInfo[] GetFields(Type obj)
{
    return obj.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
}
```

This code work great, but I dont want to work by `Values` of Enum but on `Display` name attribute.

**Question**

*How can I get `Display` name attribute by `FieldInfo` inside `foreach (var f in fields)`*

**Working solution**
*I accidentally wrote something like this:*

```
foreach (var f in fields)
{
    //insted of:
    //string i = f.GetValue(null).ToString();  
    string i = f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayAttribute>().Single().Name;
}
```

As suggested in the comments, I will try do it nicer with looping through attributes instead of fields

Comment: DisplayName is not a field, it is an Attribute.  The post sort of seems to indicate you know this, but FieldInfo wont access the Attribute values.  They are very different things - instance data and meta data

Comment: I don't use reflection so often thats why some obvious things are not obvious to me. I thought that the attribute is assigned to a given field, but you say that I have to loop through the attributes - I will try

Comment: The disadvantage of working independently from home is that you can't talk to the other people, sometimes the simplest suggestion brings good ideas! Thanks!